# gradle plugin 2.3.0 realease INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES

Tags: android, gradle-plugin

When I release the app with the `2.3.0` gradle plugin (and V2 signature) with installation the app causes `INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES` error while downgrading gradle plugin version to `2.2.3` fixes the issue! So the problem comes from where? gradle plugin version? V2 signature? key stroke (that is my whole apps key that of course can not be changed)? any bug? any thing?

Also I checked it on an empty project sample an `INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES` is exists!

Comment: what's your build tools version ? try to update your sdk to the latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [v2 signing page](https://source.android.com/security/apksigning/index.html#v2):

> The new format is backwards compatible, so APKs signed with the new signature format can be installed on older Android devices (which simply ignore the extra data added to the APK), **as long as these APKs are also v1-signed.**

You should sign with both v1 and v2 signatures (as v2 signatures [offer faster install times on Android 7.0+ devices](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0.html#apk_signature_v2))